# Meaning of "\\cM?\r?\n" in Java

Tags: java, replaceall

I got a class for something that I wanted to do in Java and it uses a line

```
text[i] = text[i].replaceAll("\\cM?\r?\n", "");
```

I completely understand that command replaceAll replaces first string with second one but don't completely understand what "\cM?\r?\n" stands for?

I would appreciate if someone can explain this text between quotes. (I did try to google it but did not find a satisfactory answer)

Comment: `\r\n` is an indication of a linebreak, that might set you in the right direction.

Comment: \cM matches a Control-M (carriage return character)

Comment: and can you explain "\cM?", thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's a regular expression.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

> \cM matches a Control-M or carriage return character
>
> \r Matches a carriage return character
>
> \n is a new line
>
> ? Matches the preceding character or subexpression zero or one time.
>   For example, "do(es)?" matches the "do" in "do" or "does". ? is
>   equivalent to {0,1}

Different operating systems have different ways to start a new line in windows its /r/n in POSIX it's different. ec ect.

Your code is essentially removing all new lines and making everything on one single line.

Answer (score 1):

It matches all new-line characters. `\cM` is Windows line endings. `\r\n` is another way of doing line endings in Windows. `\n` is the standard Unix line endings.

`?` means optional.

So match `\cM` or `\r\n` or `\n` which are all types of line endings. Should make everything on a single line...

Answer (score 1):

As I said earlier, in comment...

**Character Escapes**

> \cX matches a control character. E.g: \cm matches control-M.
>
> \r matches carriage return.
>
> \n matches linefeed.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Its a regular expression and in your case will remove all new line/line break characters which match the following : \cM will match a Control-M or carriage return character, \r is used to match a carriage return character and \n is used for a new line